Centralizer of unitary reflection
Let $r\in G$ be a reflection in a unitary reflection group over $\mathbb{C}$. Is the centralizer $C_G(r)$ a unitary reflection group?
I could not find any discussion of this question in the literature, which is surprising given that the answer is positive if $G$ is an orthogonal reflection group over the reals.
